# iPhone back buttons custom image

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

is there a simple way (Delegation? Overwriting? Category?) do globally customize all the back buttons that are being used in the navigation bars throughout my whole app?

I don't need custom text on them.
I don't need custom actions on them.
I only need custom buttons background.

Almost all my view controllers are from NIB files.
All my view controllers share the same base class.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is impossible to customize only the background, as stated by one of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In your base UIViewController class you can add the creation of your back button in the viewDidLoad method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourCustomButton];
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
}
```

where yourCustomButton is your customized button.

Comment: How do I get the default text? Note it's not always the title of the VC to the bottom of the self, sometimes it's clipped.
How do I get the action & target for the button?

Comment: I think you cannot customize only the background.